# How to make IE9 respect jquery hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a div being animated on hover (I'm using jquery's .hover() method). The div contains a form with a select. Opening the select and hovering on the options makes IE9 interpret it as having "un-hovered" the parent div, causing the second hover animation to fire . You can see it here:

http://www.oliveboutiquehotelpr.com/temp/

Any ideas on how to avoid that? It works fine in all other major browsers.

Sorry about that, here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jun6g/1/

Comment: Please include your code. We should not have to search your site to find what you are referring to. A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would also be very helpful.

Comment: After I read your question, I really wanted to tell you to "tell its parents"

Comment: just so you know: when I click on the third dropdown (number of nights) the option list is shown about 500px above where it should be. Chrome 19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by adding a variable that reflects the focus of the select and checking that everytime it wants to animate, I have fixed your problem. Javascript code here ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jun6g/16/))

**Update**

I have fixed the issue where the select has problems again after you've opened it and closed it by burring the select when the box closes. The code and link have been updated.

```
  var selectfocused = false;
  $('#block-block-5').mouseover(function () {
      selectfocused = false;
  });
  $('#block-block-5 select').focus(function () {
      selectfocused = true;
  }).blur(function () {
      selectfocused = false;
  });
  $('#block-block-5').hover(function () {
      if (selectfocused == false) {
          console.log(selectfocused);
          $(this).stop().animate({
              top: 0,
              opacity: 1
          });
      }
  }, function () {
      if (selectfocused == false) {
          $('#block-block-5 select').blur();
          $(this).stop().animate({
              top: -294,
              opacity: 0.6
          });
      }
  });
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for that. I noticed that if I select an option, the problem returns when I try to change my option. Any thoughts?

Comment: No problem for the help. Let me see what I can do about the problem that you have pointed out.

Comment: I have fixed the problem that you have noticed. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks again for helping out this newbie. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. If this has fixed your problem, please mark this as answer by clicking the checkmark under the ratings (the up and down arrows with the number between them)

Answer (score 0):

There is not select on this page. Anyway, there is no hover for select elements.